# Making entities under another entitytype

Tags: 8, entities

Suppose, I've created    -name
    -machine_name an entity_type `myentity` with its schema as:

```
-name
-machine_name
```

Next, I want to create another entity `subentity` that will be grouped under `myentity`.

I've create both the entities, but somehow during the form making, I'm clueless how to retrieve the `myentity` data under which I'm creating the `subentity` and save it.

`subentiy` schema:

```
-name
-parent (parent == myentity->machine_name)
```

Comment: Which entity is the reference field attached to?

Comment: @Clive: I've updated the question. The `subentity` `parent` field should be attached to `myentity` `machine_name`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your case is closer to the typical bundle/config entity > content entity use case (because you mention machine name, so that sounds like a config entity to me) or content entity > content entity but the way this works is pretty much the same.

You need to define a route that contains the parent entity ID, then create your entity with the reference to that and then display the add form for it.

Examples for the first use case are for example node type/node or vocabulary/term, the second are comments. While the first is usually not seen as a hierarchy/grouping, it's essentially that.

Route from [node.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.routing.yml/8):

```
node.add:
  path: '/node/add/{node_type}'
  defaults:
    _content: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::addPageTitle'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
```

[NodeController::add](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Controller%21NodeController.php/function/NodeController%3A%3Aadd/8)

```
public function add(NodeTypeInterface $node_type) {
  $account = $this->currentUser();
  $langcode = $this->moduleHandler()->invoke('language', 'get_default_langcode', array('node', $node_type->type));

  $node = $this->entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
    'uid' => $account->id(),
    'name' => $account->getUsername() ? : '',
    'type' => $node_type->type,
    'langcode' => $langcode ? $langcode : $this->languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->id,
  ));

  $form = $this->entityFormBuilder()->getForm($node);

  return $form;
}
```

The only relevant part is passing through the entity reference value ($node_type) to the new sub-entity. There are issues to make the uid/name and the langcode default value handling work by default.