# How to pass an extra argument to an entity form?

Tags: entities, 8, database

Suppose, I've two entities:

```
entityA
entityB
```

A user creates an `entityA` and has the option of creating multiple types of `entityB` referenced from a single `entityA`. For example, a parent-child relationship. Parent being `entityA` and child being `entityB`.

In the module, I want the users to select an `entityA` object, go to a new page page for creating `entityB`. So, at this point, (add-form of `entityB`) I should have the data of that particular `entityA` object that the user clicked on.

So, far I'm able to get "all" the data of `entityA` on the `add-form of entityB`, which is of no help as I'm unable to get the specific `id` of `entityA`.

The relevant code are:

**routing.yml**

```
mymodule.entityB_add:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule/{entityA}/entityB/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule_entityA_entityB.default'
    _title: 'EntityB'
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'mymodule_entityA'
```

When, I'm shown the form addition page of `entityB` (type: .`./../testentitya/entityA/add`), how do I pass the `entityA` object to the form and what will be the structure of entityB's config schema?

Comment: "entityB's config schema" -- is entityB a config entity??

Comment: @chx: Yes. Both entities are config entity.

Comment: I don't understand the difference of this question to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124065/making-entities-under-another-entitytype? seems exactly the same to me and does answer the question IMHO. Yes, it uses content and config entities/bundles, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Berdir: Yes, they don't have any difference. I've already flagged it for moderators asking them to delete it. After posting this question, I realized I should have edited that one. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2310425

This should explaine everything needed.

Here is an example how it would look like:

```
mymodule.entityB_add:
  path: '/admin/config/mymodule/{entityA}/{entityB}/add'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: 'mymodule_entityA_entityB.default'
    _title: 'EntityB'
  requirements:
    _entity_create_access: 'mymodule_entityA'
  options:
    parameters:
      entityA:
        type: entity:entity_type_a
      entityB:
        type: entity:entity_type_b
```

Comment: The example doesn't make too much sense to me, as you're *adding* an entityB, you can't pass anything to it? You only pass around entityA?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the references: config entities are simple beasts. Entity references are only supported on content entities; however you are on the way of building it out yourself tailored for your needs. So, just store a string with the id of configA and that's about it. What you do with a string is your call.